# iOS-WatchKit File Transfers Work Unreliably

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I've built an app for iOS 9 and WatchOS 2.  The iOS app will periodically transfer image files from the iPhone to the Watch. Sometimes, these are pushed from the app, sometimes the Watch requests (pulls) them. If pulled, I make the requests asynchronous, and use the exact same iOS code to transfer images in both cases.

About half the time (maybe 2/3), the file transfer works. The other times, it appears that nothing happens. This is the same whether I'm pushing or pulling images.

On the iOS side, I use code similar to this (session activated already):

```
   if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
      WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
      if (session.reachable) {
         NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

         NSURL *tempFile = [[session watchDirectoryURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"camera.png"];
         BOOL success = [imgData writeToFile: [tempFile path] atomically: NO];
         if (success) {
            NSLog(@"transferFile:metadata:");
            [session transferFile: tempFile metadata: nil];
         } else {
            NSLog(@"will not call transferFile:metadata:");
         }
      } else {
         NSLog(@"Camera watch client not reachable.");
      }
   }
```

On the watch extension side, I have a singleton that activates the watch session and receives the file:

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveFile:(WCSessionFile *)file {
   // pass the data file to the data listener (if any)
   [self.dataListener session: session didReceiveFile: file];
}
```

My "data listener" converts the file to a `UIImage` and displays it on the UI thread. However, that's probably irrelevant, as the unsuccessful operations never get that far.

During unsuccessful transfers, `session:didReceiveFile:` is never called. If I inspect the iOS app's log, however, I see these messages **only during the operations that fail**:

> Dec 26 15:10:47 hostname companionappd[74893]: (Note ) WatchKit:
> application (com.mycompany.MyApp.watchkitapp), install status: 2,
> message: application install success
>
> Dec 26 15:10:47 hostname
> companionappd[74893]: (Note ) WatchKit: Purging
> com.mycompany.MyApp.watchkitapp from installation queue, 0 apps
> remaining

What is happening here? It looks like the app is trying to reinstall the Watch app (?). When this is happening, I do **not** see the watch app crash/close and restart. It simply does nothing. No file received.

On the iOS side, I scale down the image to about 136x170 px, so the PNG files shouldn't be too big.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

### Update:

I have posted a complete, minimal project that demonstrates the problem [on Github here](https://github.com/n8r0n/hello-watch)

Comment: One comment: the session reachability boy applies to the sendMessage APIs; you can call transfer file even if the other side is not reachable (you should however check that the app is installed otherwise the file transfer will immediately fail with an error)

Comment: When you see the transfers fail, are you launching the app(s) from Xcode to attach with a debugger?

Comment: @ccjensen Thanks. These images are webcam images, so it doesn't make sense to xfer the images unless the watch client is online (I also cut out some image processing that scales/rotates images). But, more importantly, I see the same behavior whether in a Debug session, or not (viewing NSLog output in Console system.log).

Comment: Sounds like a bug report to Apple might be the best next step as this sounds like a bug in the OS. Great if you post back with the radar number too to make it easy to find for any apple engineers who happen upon this SO.

Comment: @ccjensen, that's sounding like a possibility. I'm also seeing some of these in the iOS app's log: `companionappd[79973]: (Error) WatchKit: <SPApplicationManager.m __83-[SPApplicationManager getOrBeginActivePlugInForApplication:setupBlock:completion:]_block_invoke333:508> Unable to locate plugin for 'com.mycompany.MyApp.watchkitapp' ((null))`

Comment: Try using
`[session sendMessage:@{@"file":myFileURL.absoluteString}]`
for me this works every time, note that the file must be in appGroup.

Comment: @4oby, that seems to have worked for me, as a workaround. Thanks. If you want add that as an answer (with code sample), I'd be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to transfer files from phone to watch:
In order for this to work, the file must be locate in appGroupFolder, and "*App Groups*" must be enabled from *Capabilities* tab, for phone and watch.

In order to get appGroup folder use following line of code:

```
NSURL * myFileLocationFolder = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: @"myGroupID"]; //something like group.bundle.projName
```

Once you got that use this to send message and handle response from watch:

```
 [session sendMessage:@{@"file":myFileURL.absoluteString} replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
                //got reply
            } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                //got Error
            }];
```

Even though `WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];`  I have noticed that sometimes `session` is deallocated, so you might consider using `[WCSession defaultSession];` instead.

To catch this on the phone use:

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler{
 //message[@"file"] - addres to my file
 //do stuff with it here

 replyHandler(@{@"myResponse":@"responseData"}); //this call triggers replyHandler block on the watch
}
```

Now a if you didn't forget to implement `WCSessionDelegate` and use

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
    _session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    _session.delegate = self;
    [_session activateSession];
}
//here session is @property (strong, nonatomic) WCSession * session;
```

It all should work.

Made a broader answer, hopefully will reach out to more people.

Comment: +1 thanks. I'm going to leave the question unaccepted for about a month to see if there is a more direct solution that uses `transferFile:metadata:`. If no better answers are given, I'll **accept** this answer as the solution. Don't worry ... I ask very few questions ... I won't forget :)

Comment: App groups are no longer supported in Watch OS 2: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3927

Answer (score 1):

I am now under the impression that this is a bug in the simulators. It seems to work more reliably on the Apple Watch hardware. Not sure if it's 100% reliable, though.

Apple bug report filed (#24023088). Will update status if there is any, and leave *unsolved* for any potential answers that may provide workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

For me, not a single transfer was working anymore. Polling transfer.progress showed `isTransferring == true`, but I never got beyond 0 completed units.

I ended up:

1. Deleting apps on watch and iPhone
2. Rebooting both
3. Reinstalling

And it works.

Comment: I was not receiving session(_:didFinish:error:) calls on WatchOS side. I tried: 1. restart watch, 2. reinstall app on watch, 3. restart phone. Step 3 fixed this for me. There were no error in logs on phone or watch side.